# Laravel 7 These credentials do not match with our records Auth login

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm using auth system in Laravel for register and login. I can register an user, and after this, it logged in. However, after logout I try login, but I get "these credential do not match with our records" error.

Here is my User model:

```
    use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $guarded = [];
const UPDATED_AT = null;

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
]
```

And here is my users's table migration:

```
       Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

        $table->string('username', 50);
        $table->string('email', 150);
        $table->string('PASSWORD', 500);
        $table->string('profileImage', 500)->default(null);
        $table->boolean('admin')->default('0');
        $table->time('created_At')->nullable()->useCurrent();
        $table->increments('ID');

        $table->unique('id', 'id');

    });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your controller too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to instruct the model which field you want to use as the password. By default it would be the `password` field, not `PASSWORD`. You should override the method that returns the password for the authenticatable instance:

```
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->PASSWORD;
}
```

You should just use the field how it was originally named, `password`; not sure why you changed it to `PASSWORD` in the migration.